# Brackeys 2d platformer GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Regarding the error when my player die and it tries to respawn using:

```
Transform clone = Instantiate(spawnPrefab, spawnPoint.position, spawnPoint.rotation);
Destroy(clone.gameObject, 3f);
```

But the problem is my AI can’t locate the player’s position because it is destroyed.

This is the code I used (same as in the video tutorial).

```
seeker.StartPath(transform.position, target.position, OnPathComplete);
```

However it fails to do so, because the `transform.position` is already missing.

Comment: please read this first
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to not actually delete data whose members will be needed there. You might want to add an isDeleted member which will be false at start and when you "delete" it, instead of removing it, you can set isDeleted to true. This would mean that you need to make sure that wherever you might use that data and assumed that it was not removed if found (because you physically removed it previously), check for the data to have a false value for isDeleted. Alternatively, you can have a set for deletedPlayers and move the player you remove there. Both solutions will allow you to read any of its properties, including its positions.